# Manage eslint errors with Redux Actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using react-redux for managing my presentation & container components. And i am passing a list of actions to my presentation component from my container component in the below manner :-

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ ...ActionList1, ...ActionList2 }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PresentationComponent1);
```

So i have list of actions as specified in my action file which i import and pass it on to my presentational component. Within my presentational component, i trigger these actions based on the user interaction with the screen. For e.g.

```
onRadioButtonChange(event) {
   this.props.changeRadioButtonValue(event.target.value);
}
```

In this way, there are a bunch of actions which i call from my presentational component. Now, i am using Airbnb's eslint config as base. Now, one of the rules is to validate the props validation, the failing on which it throws the below error :-

```
changeRadioButtonValue is missing in props validation
```

Now, what is the recommended way to tackle this?

- Write proptypes for each of the actions? Is there a way we can specify the entire action file in the proptypes validation, rather than individual action?
- Or disable prop validation in eslint?

Comment: There's [debate about this topic elsewhere](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/553). I don't find any of the suggestions in the thread that helpful; just providing some background reading.